# Can I source Google Fonts from my own server?

Tags: html, css, fonts

My code has this:

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

But I am sometimes finding that the googleapis is slow in my region. Can I host these fonts from my own server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. But doing it is a bit more complicated than saving CSS and the font files on your server.

The thing is, different Browsers use different font formats. Google solved this by delivering CSS rules with different font files depending on the user agent.

To support all browsers you will need the font files in TTF, WOFF, WOFF2, EOT and SVG format. But Google makes it unnecessarily hard to download the fonts files. From the google fonts site you can only download the fonts as TTF.

Also you will need cross browser CSS rules since you probably can not easily implement the user agent detection on your side.

To retrieve all formats you need to request the CSS file from Google with different user agents. [Here](http://ijotted.blogspot.de/2012/05/download-eot-ttf-woff-formats-of-font.html) is an outdated blog article listing some of the user agent strings to use. In the meantime WOFF2 was added and to actually get EOT you now need to send an IE6 user agent. IE7+ now will result in WOFF.

You can use the tool http://www.localfont.com/ to easily download all font formats and the corresponding X-Browser CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: **YES**

A quick googling revealed me these information.

Info Pages:

http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro

https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Source+Code+Pro

They both are under the SIL Open Font License, 1.1

And this license do not impose much restrictions and allows you to host the font on your website.

http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ofl-faq_web#23261834

http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ofl-faq_web#c26665c2

Answer (score 0):

you have to host the css files on your server , and also you have to write the code is it fails to load from the server then it pick up from some local storage or you have provide another server link .

Answer (score -1):

yes you can. [image]

marked in red in the top right corner of google fonts there is a download link.

source:
 https://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/